# Delay in output relative to input

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, output

This is code for a lift (elevator). I am getting some delay in output. How can I get rid of these delays?

Code:

```
module lift(input clk_in,rst,input [1:0]r,output reg [2:0]out,
output reg clk_out);
parameter g0 = 4'b0000; //ground floor with no action
parameter g1 = 4'b0001; //ground floor with d1 output
parameter g2 = 4'b0010; //ground floor with d2 output
parameter f0 = 4'b0011; //first floor
parameter f1 = 4'b0100; //first floor with up1
parameter f2 = 4'b0101; //first floor with d1
parameter s0 = 4'b0110; //second floor
parameter s1 = 4'b0111; //second floor with up1
parameter s2 = 4'b1000; //second floor with up2
//outputs
parameter n = 3'b000;
parameter d1 = 3'b001;
parameter d2 = 3'b010;
parameter up1 = 3'b011;
parameter up2 = 3'b100;
//inputs
parameter r0 = 2'b00;
parameter r1 = 2'b01;
parameter r2 = 2'b10;
//current and next state registers
reg [3:0] state, nxt_state;
//clockDivider
reg[15:0]counter=16'd0;
parameter DIVISOR = 16'd32768;
always @(posedge clk_in)
begin
counter<=counter+16'd1;
if(counter>=(DIVISOR-1))
begin
counter<=16'd0;
end
clk_out<=(counter<DIVISOR/2)?1'b1:1'b0;
end
always@(posedge clk_out,posedge rst) begin
if(rst == 1)
state <= g0;
else
state <= nxt_state;
end
always@(state ,r) begin
case(state)
g0 : begin
if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g0;
else if(r==r1)
nxt_state <= f1;
else
nxt_state <= s2;
end
g1 : begin
if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g0;
else if(r==r1)
nxt_state <= f1;
else
nxt_state <= s2;
end
g2 : begin
if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g0;
else if(r==r1)
nxt_state <= f1;
else
nxt_state <= s2;
end
f0 : begin
if(r == r1)
nxt_state <= f0;
else if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g1;
else
nxt_state <= s1;
end
f1 : begin
if(r == r1)
nxt_state <= f0;
else if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g1;
else
nxt_state <= s1;
end
f2 : begin
if(r == r1)
nxt_state <= f0;
else if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g1;
else
nxt_state <= s1;
end
s0 : begin
if(r == r2)
nxt_state <= s0;
else if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g2;
else
nxt_state <= f2;
end
s1 : begin
if(r == r2)
nxt_state <= s0;
else if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g2;
else
nxt_state <= f2;
end
s2 : begin
if(r == r2)
nxt_state <= s0;
else if(r == r0)
nxt_state <= g2;
else
nxt_state <= f2;
end
default : nxt_state <= g0;
endcase
end
always@(state) begin
case(state)
g0 : out <= n;
g1 : out <= d1;
g2 : out <= d2;
f0 : out <= n;
f1 : out <= up1;
f2 : out <= d1;
s0 : out <= n;
s1 : out <= up1;
s2 : out <= up2;
endcase
end
endmodule
```

testbench:

```
module tb();
reg clk_in;
reg rst;
reg [1:0]r;
wire [2:0] out;
wire clk_out;
lift uut(clk_in,rst,r,out,clk_out);
initial begin
clk_in = 0;
forever #15259 clk_in=~clk_in;
end
initial begin
// Initialize Inputs
r = 2'b00;
rst = 1;
// Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
#91554;
rst = 0;
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b00;
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b01;
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b10;
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b00;
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b10;
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b01;
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

[image: Simulation]

Answer (score 0):

> always@(posedge **clk_out**,posedge rst) begin

Apparently your FSM is clocked by clk_out. You cannot get rid of this delay, it is an inherent property of clock-synchronous logic design. The entire idea of robust digital logic is based on these delays. If you want to reduce the delay, use faster clock.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the delay between the `r` input and the `out` output by changing the testbench code.

Your testbench currently waits for the `negedge` of `clk_out` before changing the `r` input, but you can change `r` **at any time you like**.

For example, if you change

```
@(negedge clk_out);
r = 2'b00;
```

to

```
@(posedge clk_out);
r = 2'b00;
```

That will remove the delay between `r` and `out` (as seen in the waves below).  You can change `negedge` to `posedge` everywhere in the testbench.

[image: waves]

You need to make sure this satisfies your timing requirements.

Here is the full `initial` block:

```
initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  r = 2'b00;
  rst = 1;
  // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  #91554;
  rst = 0;
  @(posedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b00;
  @(posedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b01;
  @(posedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b10;
  @(posedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b00;
  @(posedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b10; 
  @(posedge clk_out);
  r = 2'b01;
  $finish;
end
```

Comment: when it changed to posedge, r changes at first posedge and out changes at the next posedge which increased the delay

Comment: @had:  I added waveforms to my answer to show that there is no delay between r and out. They change at the same time. I also added the full code so you can reproduce it.  This was just one possible suggestion.  **You can change r at any time you like.**